# WCF Service reference namespace cannot be found

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces, wcf-client, service-reference

I've got a local WCF service in my solution which I have referenced.  However my controller class is not able to pick up the Service namespace?   Traditionally I would use svcUtil to write a wrapper class but as this is internal I though I could simply add 'Service Reference', tap into the namespace then simple invoke my service (ie var service = new QServiceReference.MyClass();)

I'm unable to show pictures so here's the structure for my solution,

```
Solution  
-> Services Folder
    -> QService Folder
       QService Project  
-> Web Folder
    -> Zipporah.Queuing.Web (project)
       -> Services References
          -> QServiceReference
       -> Controllers Folder
          -> KioskProcessController
```

My class (KioskProcessController) is as follows:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Zipporah.Queuing.Web.QServiceReference; (ITS THIS NAMESPACE REFERENCE THAT DOES NOT WORK)

namespace Zipporah.Queuing.Web.Controllers
{
    public class KioskProcessController : ZipController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ViewResult Queue()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ViewResult PreAppointment()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if that structure is not clear (as aforementioned i cannot post pictures)

Any clues or thoughts would be most appreciated?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The namespace generated for your WCF Client might be different than the one you are `using`. In your `Solution Explorer` window, when you select your `Service References` folder, you can enable the `Show All Files` button and then navigate to file `Reference.cs` as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

Then, in `Reference.cs` file, you can find the ***actual generated namespace*** by the Add Service Reference dialog, which you can use in your other file with a `using` statement.

Comment: Thanks CSharpVJ.  It would appear the the auto generated code in Reference.cs is blank which would explain a lot :)  again thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, Svcutil and VS2010 handle namespaces differently.

Comment: Subject to this blank reference I've since found the underlying issue.  2 actually.  Firstly, I did not have the correct data contracts set up on my classes and I was missing dependency mappers.  Secondly the app config had incorrect values in the endpoint.  Lessons learnt.